# Extending multiple parents

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to do this:

```
{% extends 'main_page.html','search.html' %}
{% block search %}[search bar code goes here]{% endblock %}
```

But, from what I've seen, I can't, at least, not like that. So what do I do?

ETA: So I want to put a search bar in my main page, and also in my dedicated 'search' page (which will also have more involved search functionality, and hopefully data visualization stuff, god willing.) DRY suggests writing two different copies of the same code, one extending main_page.html and the other extending search.html is bad. To be fair, I'm pretty new at Django, and I don't really understand the difference between {% include %} and {% extends %}.

Comment: Instead of posting the question as a non-working code example, you should explain in words what you're trying to achieve, and then - as a supplement - post the code that you've tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% block search %}
    {% include "search.html" %}
{% endblock search %}
```

this should do (btw: not much information provided, i improvised trying to spot what you want to do. add some more if this isn't what you need and i may change my answer)

[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include) from django docs for the include tag